# Can't read a specific file under /sys filesystem

Tags: ubuntu, files, wifi

While searching for ways to obtain various WiFi information, I found `/sys/class/net/wlan7/speed` file. Problem is, even though all read permissions are granted, I can't read it.

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/net/wlan7/speed                                                                                       
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 3月  24 15:08 /sys/class/net/wlan7/speed

$ sudo cat /sys/class/net/wlan7/speed                                                                                    
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
cat: /sys/class/net/wlan7/speed: Invalid argument
```

I can stat the file, I can list with `ls`, but every time I try to read it ( with `hexdump`, with `cat`, with Python in binary reading mode, etc. ) it shows invalid argument error.

`strace` shows that error apparently occurs at this point:

```
read(3, 0x7f6ad6b44000, 131072)         = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
write(2, "cat: ", 5cat: )                    = 5
write(2, "/sys/class/net/wlan7/speed", 26/sys/class/net/wlan7/speed) = 26
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
```

( link to full trace paste: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24252504/ )

By contrast , the corresponding file for the ethernet interface works:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/eth3/speed                              
10
```

So basically my question is this: how do I read this file ?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-67-generic , AR9565 WiFi adapter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file `/sys/class/net/<iface>/speed` is only valid for devices that support *ethtool get_settings* method, which mostly applies to Ethernet adapters.

To get the speed of a WiFi device, you can use `iwconfig` or `iwlist`.

```
iwconfig wlan7
iwlist wlan7 rate
```

---

From the Kernel documentation:

```
What:       /sys/class/net/<iface>/speed
...  
Description:
        Indicates the interface latest or current speed value. Value is
        an integer representing the link speed in Mbits/sec.

        Note: this attribute is only valid for interfaces that implement
        the ethtool get_settings method (mostly Ethernet ).
```

Comment: One small request: can you provide the link to the kernel documentation from which the quote comes ? I would like to read more there